# How can I /testfor a mob's health in Minecraft Java 1.11?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map for 1.11, and I need to test for a zombie with a certain health. I tried:

```
/testfor @e[type=zombie] {CustomName:"HEROBRINE",Health:9s}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a mobs health, on Java 1.17](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387385/how-to-detect-a-mobs-health-on-java-1-17)

Comment: Closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer question because this one has an outdated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `Health` tag's datatype was changed from Short to Float in 1.9, while the old `HealF` tag was removed. To declare a Float, you append the numerical value with an "f". You can also check the custom name with the `name` parameter in the selector instead of detecting it through raw NBT data:

```
/testfor @e[type=zombie,name=HEROBRINE] {Health:9f}
```

However, because the datatype is Float, it is highly unlikely that its health will be exactly 9.0. If at any point the mob takes a fraction of health, it essentially becomes impossible to detect the health of non-player entities.